# Concatenating two columns adds a 0 infront of 4 digit postal codes in some cases

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following code that has been working as intended until recently

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file1 = "xyz.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file1)
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:,.2f}'.format  

df.loc[~df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]'), 'ZipCleaned'] = df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.slice(stop=5)
df.loc[df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.contains('[A-Za-z]'), 'ZipCleaned'] = df['Ship To Customer Zip'].str.replace(' |-','')

df['revenue'] = df['revenue'].replace('\$|,','', regex=True).replace('\(','-', regex=True).replace('\)','', regex=True)

df['Customer ID'] = df['Ship To Customer'] + df['ZipCleaned']
```

The objective of the code is to create a column called "Customer ID" that concatenates the 'Ship to Customer' and "ZipCleaned" columns.

Problem:  For zip codes where users have entered only four numbers, in some cases, the last line of code above adds a zero ("0") in front of the zip cleaned column and in other cases it doesn't.  I noticed that the code just started adding the zero in front to more recent months in my database (the data goes back several years).  I would prefer not to include a zero in front in cases where the zip code field only contains 4 digits.

Below is an example of the dataframe

[image]

Comment: Could you provide an example of the dataframe?

Comment: Please do not paste an image of data, but enter data into a dataframe in code. Also, since your question is specifically about 4-digit zips (although that doesn't square with my understanding of a zip code), you should include some four-digit zips that are or are not leading to zeros being added. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry, edited my comment above

Comment: but the data I have is hundreds of thousands of rows and in a csv.  you want me to put a sample of that into a dataframe in the code?

Comment: I suggest replacing your `df=pd.read_csv(...)` with `df = pd.DataFrame({...})`, and include 5-10 rows, at least 2-3 of which end up being not processed how you want. You should make it clear how the output of your code is not how you want, ideally by also providing code for `desired_output_df = pd.DataFrame({...})` that we can compare with the result of running your code through the `df` you give us for input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to resolve this but i'm not sure if it's the correct approach.  To remove the zero from in front of the zip codes I've added in the following code to convert the field into a string.

```
df['ZipCleaned'] = df['ZipCleaned'].astype(str)
```

Max Power, to answer your question about the 4-digit-zip codes, when i save my data in csv, it removes the "0" from those zip codes that begin with "0" there by converting them to five digits (it did this in some cases and not in other cases there by causing inconsistencies in my data set).

Comment: For your 4-digit issue, I suggest to use `pd.read_csv(..., dtype={'ZipCleand': str})`

Comment: If you're trying to prevent a leading zero from being dropped (which is a good idea for zip codes), you should use pe-perry's code above to read any zip data fields from csv as strings. Don't read them in (with ambiguous/unpredictable type) and then convert them to strings. I was thrown by the following line in your question though, when you said your problem was you want 4-digit zips and the code was adding zeros: "For zip codes where users have entered only four numbers, in some cases, the last line of code above adds a zero ("0")"